# Where can I get the Windows Workflow "wca.exe" application?

Tags: .net-3.5

I am walking through the MS Press Windows Workflow Step-by-Step book and in chapter 8 it mentions a tool with the filename "wca.exe".  This is supposed to be able to generate workflow communication helper classes based on an interface you provide it.  I can't find that file.  I thought it would be in the latest .NET 3.5 SDK, but I just downloaded and fully installed, and it's not there.  Also, some MSDN forum posts had links posted that just go to 404s.  So, where can I find wca.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be part of the .NET 3 SDK (and later version as well). If you've already installed this, the path might look something like

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin\wca.exe

More info on [Guy Burstein's blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2006/12/24/wca.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, with Visual Studio 2008 installed, it's in 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin